# Vertically center content inside an inline parent

Tags: css, inline, center

Trying to create an adaptive post meta for a post card.

The idea is that sometimes the post meta could have more than one category inside and because of that I need somehow to wrap the items, but at the same time to vertically center the `li` content (like the avatar and icons).

I tried to apply `display: inline-flex` to the `.entry-meta` in order to be able to use the `align-items: center` property but in this case the list items - `li`'s are not anymore wrapping nice like when applying `display: inline` to `li`.

---

**1. The `display: inline` method (not centering items vertically)**

This method is wrapping correctly and how I want all the list items but it can't center vertically the content (like the avatar and icons)

```css
article {
  max-width: 450px;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

article a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.entry-meta {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.entry-meta li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #FA7059;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: #BE4C4E;
}
```

```html
<article>  
 <ul class="entry-meta">

  <li class="author">
   <div class="avatar">
   </div>
   
   <span>By&nbsp;</span>

   <a href="#">Admin</a>
  </li>

  <li class="date">
   <span>On&nbsp;</span>
   <time>Feb 22, 2019</time>
  </li>

  <li>
   <span>On&nbsp;</span>
   <a href="#">2 Comments</a>
  </li>

  <li class="categories">
   <span class="icon">
   </span>

   <a href="#">Food</a>
   <a href="#">Nature</a>
   <a href="#">People</a>
   <a href="#">Travel</a>
   <a href="#">Trends</a>
   <a href="">Business</a>
   <a href="">Sport</a>
   <a href="">Music</a>
   <a href="">Gadgets</a>
   <a href="#">Uncategorized</a>
  </li>

  <li class="tags">
      <span class="icon">
   </span>
      
   <a href="">Red</a>
   <a href="">Blue</a>
   <a href="">Green</a>
   <a href="">Yellow</a>
  </li>

 </ul>
</article>
```

**2. The `display: inline-flex` method**

The category `li` is not wrapped correctly, it breaks in a new line, but in exchange the content is vertically centered like I need.

```css
article {
  max-width: 450px;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

article a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.entry-meta {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.entry-meta li {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #FA7059;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: #BE4C4E;
}
```

```html
<article>  
 <ul class="entry-meta">

  <li class="author">
   <div class="avatar">
   </div>
   
   <span>By&nbsp;</span>

   <a href="#">Admin</a>
  </li>

  <li class="date">
   <span>On&nbsp;</span>
   <time>Feb 22, 2019</time>
  </li>

  <li>
   <span>On&nbsp;</span>
   <a href="#">2 Comments</a>
  </li>

  <li class="categories">
   <span class="icon">
   </span>

   <a href="#">Food</a>
   <a href="#">Nature</a>
   <a href="#">People</a>
   <a href="#">Travel</a>
   <a href="#">Trends</a>
   <a href="">Business</a>
   <a href="">Sport</a>
   <a href="">Music</a>
   <a href="">Gadgets</a>
   <a href="#">Uncategorized</a>
  </li>

  <li class="tags">
      <span class="icon">
   </span>
      
   <a href="">Red</a>
   <a href="">Blue</a>
   <a href="">Green</a>
   <a href="">Yellow</a>
  </li>

 </ul>
</article>
```

So, in other words, I need somehow to keep the list items to wrap like they are with `display: inline` but at the same time center vertically the content inside.

P.S. the `vertical-align: middle` property doesn't really help :)

Comment: Can you please create a minimal example, rather than the full lengthy code?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to make it more minimal than this in order to show the entire idea... Hope you will understand me right.

Answer (score 0):

> P.S. the vertical-align: middle property doesn't really help :)

This is actually what you need (applied to `.avatar`)

```css
article {
  max-width: 450px;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

article a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.entry-meta {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.entry-meta li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.avatar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #FA7059;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  background: #BE4C4E;
}
```

```html
<article>  
 <ul class="entry-meta">

  <li class="author">
   <div class="avatar">
   </div>
   
   <span>By&nbsp;</span>

   <a href="#">Admin</a>
  </li>

  <li class="date">
   <span>On&nbsp;</span>
   <time>Feb 22, 2019</time>
  </li>

  <li>
   <span>On&nbsp;</span>
   <a href="#">2 Comments</a>
  </li>

  <li class="categories">
   <span class="icon">
   </span>

   <a href="#">Food</a>
   <a href="#">Nature</a>
   <a href="#">People</a>
   <a href="#">Travel</a>
   <a href="#">Trends</a>
   <a href="">Business</a>
   <a href="">Sport</a>
   <a href="">Music</a>
   <a href="">Gadgets</a>
   <a href="#">Uncategorized</a>
  </li>

  <li class="tags">
      <span class="icon">
   </span>
      
   <a href="">Red</a>
   <a href="">Blue</a>
   <a href="">Green</a>
   <a href="">Yellow</a>
  </li>

 </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: Yep, it works for the avatar, but when I apply `vertical-align: middle` to `.icon` - the icon goes way too much to the bottom, and it's not centered nice like when you use the `display: inline-flex` thought...

Comment: @Sergiu use `vertical-align: text-top;` for the icons

Comment: @Termani thank you, but this doesn't really work well after you increase the font size of the entire `.entry-meta`, the icon is no more vertically centered. The best way will be to use `display: inline-flex` in combination with `align-items: center` but going this way is making the categories and tags `li` to break in a new row :(